# numba python, list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I am trying to use a list of lists with numba. I have had difficulties trying to get it to recognize the types

the code looks like the below

```
from numba.typed import List
from numba import njit


@njit()
def build_permutations(position_length, starting_leverage, ending_leverage, starting_amount=100000):
    current_permutation = np.full(position_length, starting_leverage)
    permutations = []
    sublist = List()

    while True:
        # Apply the filter condition
        if ((np.sum(current_permutation) * 440000) / starting_amount > 10) and ((np.sum(current_permutation) * 440000) / starting_amount < 100):
            sublist.append(List(current_permutation))

            if len(sublist) == 100_000_000:
                permutations.append(sublist)
                sublist = []

        # Generate the next permutation
        i = position_length - 1
        while i >= 0 and current_permutation[i] == ending_leverage:
            current_permutation[i] = starting_leverage
            i -= 1

        if i < 0:
            break

        current_permutation[i] += 1

    # Append the remaining sublist if it's not empty
    if sublist:
        permutations.append(sublist)

    return permutations
```

but i get the error

```
Cannot unify ListType[ListType[int64]] and list(undefined)<iv=None> for 'sublist.3', defined at main.py (452)
```

which makes sense, because i'm not definig the type of list it is. However I haven't been able to find a way to define a list of lists

side note: If it is easier to make it a list of tuples, that also works

Answer (score 0):

Numba Typed_List is a "type-homogeneous list", meaning that all elements within a single typed_list must be of the same type.

This Error message is telling you that `sublist` of type `ListType[ListType[int64]]` (as you defined because you just did: `sublist.append(List(current_permutation))` ) and an empty python list `[]` of type `list(undefined)<iv=None>` is not interchangable. Thus, this specific line in your code is invalid: `sublist = []`.

For example, if you do:

```
example = List()
example = []
```

similar Error message will occur, telling you that Numba doesn't like conversion between python list and numba typed-list.

In addition to this, since typed-list is an experimental feature in Numba with occasional bugs, and because numba favors numpy array over python lists in no-python mode (the speed difference is huge!), I recommend you reconsider whether you really wish to use list and njit together.